# Extracting HTML data with sed

Tags: html, bash, sed, web-scraping

I need to extract the below bolded data from the html code below:

```
<div class="name-ad hidden" data-count="91">
<div class="name-data-item" data-name="**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS**" data-
count="92">
<div class="name-data-name">Washington NH</div>                 
<div class="name-data-location">Sullivan, Washington, 
NH<br></div><div class="name-data-status">**I NEED TO 
SCRAPE THIS AS WELL**</div> </div>
```

Can this be done with the sed command? If not, how can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Your code snippet is not valid. Please, could you post valid input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `awk`:

```
$ cat file
<div class="name-ad hidden" data-count="91">
<div class="name-data-item" data-name="**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS**" data-
count="92">
<div class="name-data-name">Washington NH</div>                 
<div class="name-data-location">Sullivan, Washington, 
NH<br></div><div class="name-data-status">**I NEED TO 
SCRAPE THIS AS WELL**</div> </div>

$ awk -F\" '/name-data-item/ {print $4}' file
**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS**
```

Comment: You miss `**I NEED TO 
SCRAPE THIS AS WELL**`

Comment: `awk -F\" '/name-data-(item|status)/ {print $4}' file` should do the trick for both.

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet` and this more vaild html (file.html):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="name-ad hidden" data-count="91">
      <div class="name-data-item" data-name="**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS**" data-count="92">
        <div class="name-data-name">Washington NH</div>                 
        <div class="name-data-location">Sullivan, Washington, NH<br /></div>
        <div class="name-data-status">**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS AS WELL**</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Command:

```
xmlstarlet sel --html -t \
    -v "//html/body/div/div/@data-name" \
    -v "//html/body/div/div/div[@class='name-data-status']" file.html
```

Output:

```
**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS****I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS AS WELL**
```

or with a newline:

```
xmlstarlet sel --html -t \
    -v "//html/body/div/div/@data-name" \
    -n \
    -v "//html/body/div/div/div[@class='name-data-status']" file.html
```

Output:

```
**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS**
**I NEED TO SCRAPE THIS AS WELL**
```